# Should a SaaS application have a standard homepage?

Tags: homepage, landing-page

I work with a product that contains two large applications. These applications are separate, but work together in some ways. The smaller (and less used) of the two is undergoing a re-skin in terms of styling for the UI. It has a standard homepage with just links to various useful pages within the app. Analytics data and research with users has shown us that nobody is using this page. They go to the nav and straight to the page they need from there. Because of this, we're wondering what may need to change. Here are the ideas:

- General overview of the product (not a huge step from what we have now)
- Dashboard interface (could show same data for all but would be much more useful if tailored to the role of the user)
- User-defined content (widgets the user can select to custom build what they want to see)
- No "home" page... instead either show initial Welcome screen for onboarding purposes which can be closed and accessed somewhere in the app later for reference, then take them from there after to the last page they visited or a page they set as their preferred landing page

The last item seems to be the preferred and most useful route based on early conversations with users. The other application (the larger), has both an overview page that they can access via a "home" link, and takes them to the last page they were on when re-entering the app.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually asked your users?

Answer (score 1):

I think in part you have answered your own question:

> "Analytics data and research with users has shown us that nobody is using this page."
>
> "The last item seems to be the preferred and most useful route based on early conversations with users."

If the users prefer there being no standard homepage, then **there should be no standard homepage**.

There's no substitute for user research, [even with small numbers](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-you-only-need-to-test-with-5-users/) :)

---

It sounds like the decision to include a homepage was made *before* working out what purpose it serves, or simply to fill empty space.

Instead, you should omit the homepage and only think about it **when there's a user goal which can be satisfied using a homepage**.

Placing the onboarding process on the homepage ***will* satisfy the goals of new users**.

Comment: Thank you both! Great feedback:) And yes, the applications were totally separate initially so perhaps at that time the homepage made sense. The decision was made before I was involved. Now that they have been pulled under the same umbrella as one product, it seems less useful. Thanks again!